# Frequency of object atribute value in ArrayList

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

This is my list:

```
List < Game > players = new ArrayList < > ();
```

I need to find out a way to calculate how many objects in ArrayList contain a name that equals to "Dan" for example.

I tried this in a for loop but doesn't work:

```
Collections.frequency(players.get( i ).name, "Dan")
```

Comment: Why is a list of `Game` called `players`?

Comment: First parameter of `Collections.frequency` should be a `Collection`. It uses `equals` method to compare objects of the same type.

Comment: @shmosel because my class is named Game and my file name is Game.java :) I know I shouldn't have named it that way. But I'm studying java for a couple of months now, so as I'm new to java let the name be Game ))  I'll change it afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 8 solution:

```
int count = players.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.name.equals("Dan"))
        .count();
```

Java 7 solution:

```
int count = 0;
for (Game player : players) {
    if (player.name.equals("Dan")) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it this way, but if you really want to use `Collections.frequency` you need to implement the `equals` method in your `Game` class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if(o == null || !(o instanceof Player)) return false;
    Player p = (Player) o;
    return name.equals(p.getName());
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
Game dan = new Game("dan");
Collections.frequency(players, dan);
```

(Maybe your Game class should be named `Player`)

Comment: @shmosel Yes, but it helps OP to understand how it works. Your answer is the way to go.

Comment: OP might not realize the problems with this approach. I would add a disclaimer.

Comment: Also, in context it should be `Game dan = new Game("dan");`, etc.... or you should tell OP why his design is wrong.