# Count occurrences in a Object ArrayList of a Attribute

Tags: java, list, count

How can I count the occurrences of the `String type` field/attribute that equals weapon in the stated `ArrayList<Item>`. I added three faulty formatted `System.out.println()`;

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Main{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Item> gear;
        
        gear.add(new Item("weapon", 1, 1));
        gear.add(new Item("weapon", 1, 1));
        gear.add(new Item("helmet", 1, 1));
        gear.add(new Item("ring", 1, 1));
        gear.add(new Item("weapon", 1, 1));
        gear.add(new Item("ring", 1, 1));
        
        System.out.println(Collections.frequency(gear.getType(), "weapon"));
        System.out.println(Collections.frequency(gear.getType(), "helmet"));
        System.out.println(Collections.frequency(gear.getType(), "ring"));
    }
    
    class Item{
        String type;
        int weight;
        int strength;
        
        public Item(String type, int weight, int strength) {
            super();
            this.type = type;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.strength = strength;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Wanted output:

```
3
1
2
```

Comment: You want to count the number of elements in `gear` whose `type` attribute is _weapon_. Is that correct?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: This question has been asked and answered more than once already on SO. See [how to get frequency of Object's field in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670449/how-to-get-frequency-of-objects-field-in-arraylist) and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070638/frequency-of-object-atribute-value-in-arraylist. Did you try Googling for ___java attribute frequency list___ ?

Comment: @Abra with what keywords did you find a duplicate just asking for the future
thank you
and yes I did but I only found examples regarding int and string list

Comment: you are right, I often lack the correct keywords
sadly I did not learn about streams yet but it is upcoming topic for my OCP exam
I just started 3 months ago with Java and was only working with script languages before
and if im not able to find the correct answer I often create a new one
but now that this is locked I cant delete it and I already did an additional edit
so if you can label it as duplicate, that would be most welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using lambdas its quite simple,

```
String gearType = "Weapon";
long fequency = gear.stream().filter(gearInput -> gearInput.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(gearType)).count();
```

You can wrap this within a function, passing gearType as parameter.

Comment: think you're missing a "g" before .getType()

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Item {
    String type;
    int weight;
    int strength;
    
    Item(String ty, int we, int st)
    {
        type = ty;
        weight = we;
        strength = st;
    }
    String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
}

private int getFrequency(ArrayList<Item> list, String type)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (Item object: list) {
        if (object.getType().equals(type))
            counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   ArrayList<Item> gear = new ArrayList<Item>();
   gear.add( new Item("weapon",1,10) );
   gear.add( new Item("dog",2,23) );
   gear.add( new Item("none",4,44) );
   gear.add( new Item("car",1,88) );
   gear.add( new Item("weapon",65,20) );

   System.out.println("weapon elements: "+ this.getFrequency(gear,"weapon"));
   System.out.println("weapon elements: "+ this.getFrequency(gear,"helmet"));
   System.out.println("weapon elements: "+ this.getFrequency(gear,"ring"));
}
// Output: weapon elements: 2
```

Comment: I was hoping for a oneliner, maybe lambda but I appreciate your input very much